# Is there a way to close(merge) an SO-family account?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I accidentally created two accounts with my two openids, instead of putting both openids on the same account.  I want to close one of my accounts so I can associate both openids on the same account.

How can it be done?

Comment: Email team@stackoverflow.com, they can delete/merge accounts for you. Just be prepared to demonstrate ownership of both accounts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send an email team@stackoverflow.com explaining the situation.

If you can, edit the duplicate, and write in the description that it is a dup of your other account. You may also want to edit the description of the original. This will help prove that the person who owns the duplicate account, is in fact the same person who owns the other account.

I have actually done this, and it worked flawlessly.

I think that there should probably be a warning, if you are trying to log in with an OpenID that is not associated with any account.

Comment: There now is a warning if you try to login with a new OpenID, that isn't associated with any account.

Answer (score 4):

Just email team@stackoverflow.com with your details.

Answer (score 2):

Send an email to the team (team@stackoverflow.com). They can help you with this if you can prove you are really who you are.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the big problems with OpenId, if you don't have your own webpage providing, then you need to stick to one provider for the SOs.

Comment: Never had a problem. Myopenid has always worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: If your provider is down and you connect to SO with a different provider, then you'll be on a new account, not your normal one.  So no rep, badges, etc.  I've had my provider go down before, and I wasn't able to SO because of it.

Comment: @Lance Set up an alternate ID on your account.

Comment: @ChrisF, Thanks that looks like it worked, now I have a backup.