# Disabling a Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/delete-my-account)
>   [How do I consolidate my stackoverflow accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3948/how-do-i-consolodate-my-stackoverflow-accounts)

How do I disable a Stack Overflow user account? I made two accounts by mistake.

Comment: should be asked in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/delete-my-account

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3948/how-do-i-consolodate-my-stackoverflow-accounts

Answer (score 2):

Send e-mail to team@stackoverflow.com