# How can I merge two Stack Overflow accounts and maintain all contributions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Can I merge two Stack Overflow accounts into single account? For example,
I used to log in to Stack Overflow with my Google account sometimes, and other times with my Yahoo account.

Can I export the questions and answers that I created by those accounts to a single account (say an OpenID account)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste), [How do I consolidate my stackoverflow accounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3948/how-do-i-consolidate-my-stackoverflow-accounts)

Comment: Flag a question/answer by the account you wish to disappear from the account you wish it to be merged into for moderator attention.  Ask to merge the account flagged into your new one.  Everything will be moved from the first account (the flagged one) into the account that did the flagging.