# How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)

Tags: support, faq, association, merge-accounts, anonymous

I accidentally posted a question without being logged in. Is there a way to associate that question with my account?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

> For more information, visit "[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

---

a.k.a. How can you link a registered account to a cookie-based account?
a.k.a. How do I merge an unregistered account with a registered account
a.k.a. Merging users
a.k.a. How do I associate anonymous questions I’ve asked with my registered account?
a.k.a. Is there a way to claim an unregistered user?
(in case anyone searches with those terms)

Answer (score 97):

To merge any two accounts, follow the procedure outlined on the ["User Merge" help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts):

> ### I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
>
> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
> sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I
> need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange
> Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can
> confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email
> address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

If you're into URL modification, you can just go directly to `https://$site/help/merging-accounts`. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts, https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts, and so on.

Comment: When I put the link for my [unregistered account](https://superuser.com/users/1801482/user1801482), SE does not go through and keeps telling me to provide the missing URL. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @a_sid because you deleted it.